# Can kentico grant permission for a web part?

Tags: permissions, content-management-system, kentico

One of my page contains more than 5 web parts, I want to give role A full control to one of the web parts,but role A should not have access to modify other web parts. any body has any idea on whether it is workable or not?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I thought the question was easy to read and understand. Not sure why you down voted, other than he may have been able to figure this out in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Kentico doesn't support permission configuration to specific role at webpart level.
If you really want to add permission on the role bases you can register your webparts as widgets and give permission on widget level.

How to configure role based widget level permission.

[image: snapshot]

1. Open widget module in kentico admin.
2. Then select your widget and go to security tab.
3. Select Authorized role.
4. Add set allowed for role user in he list

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Prashant. I actually have a slider module on my page, I want a specific role to manage this slider. This role can add, delete and edit the pictures in this slider. I tried convert the webpart into widget and add the data source for this widget. I wonder is there a way that some roles can update the datasource without access to the admin interface? do you have any advice for this? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The widget approach is what you need to do, but if for some reason you need to have someone who had design access not be allowed to modify a certain web part... An option (not recommended though) is to use a macro in the visible field of the web part properties to make it invisible based on the role, you would have to do that for all fields though and it would apply to any instance of that web part.